# best_in_place gem with rails4 not displaying errors

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, best-in-place

I am trying to use the best_in_place gem with a Rails 4 app.  I can
get it to update valid edits to a field fine, but if I enter an
invalid value, I don't see error messages.  I have added the .purr
styling rules, but still no joy.

I use the following in the controller:

```
def update
  @transact = Transact.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @transact.update_attributes(transact_params)
      flash[:notice] = 'Transaction was successfully updated.'
      format.html { redirect_to(@transact) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
      format.json { respond_with_bip(@transact) }
    else
      @errors = @transact.errors
      format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @transact.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      # format.json {
      #   render :json => @errors.full_messages,
      #   :status => :unprocessable_entity
      # }
      format.json { respond_with_bip(@transact) }
    end
  end
end
```

And I've also tried the commented-out code in the above, with similar results.

Here is what the server responds on an invalid value:

```
Processing by TransactsController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"transact"=>{"shares"=>"6741433.0x"}, "authenticity_token"=>"e+1ZEhVYuEMDURf81Kcxg0Ld28BfY60rRFRSZUq8RsY=", "id"=>"144314"}
  Transact Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "transacts".* FROM "transacts" WHERE "transacts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "144314"]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 60ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
```

Is there any thing obvious I am doing wrong?

Comment: Answer: I was not including best_in_place.purr.js in my javascript assets in addition to best_in_place.js.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. My solution was to include ALL these three lines in application.js:

```
//= require best_in_place
//= require best_in_place.purr
//= require jquery.purr
```

If jquery.purr or best_in_place.purr was left out, no error message was displayed to the user.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, see my comment above: I was not including best_in_place.purr.js in my javascript assets in addition to best_in_place.js.

Hope it helps someone else overlooking this.

I considered this answered.